# How can I use the accelemetor to move my ccpsprite/image to the left and right? (like in doodle jump)

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, accelerometer

I tried to use the code from http://github.com/haqu/tweejump but it's not smooth...it makes 10-20px teleports :(.

Is there a better way?

Some code would be great.

Thank you very much!

:)

PS: I'm using cocos2d.

Answer (score 1):

Calculate the desired velocity of your sprite as a function of accelerometer measurement.

The simplest way is to use linear dependence:
`spriteVel = cft*accValue`,
where cft is some coefficient showing how fast will your sprite move

Another way is to say that acceleration of your sprite is a linear function of accelerometer measurement:
`spriteAcc = cft*accValue` and the to calculate velocity as a linear function of acceleration:
`spriteVel = spriteInitVel + time*accValue`

That can be easy implemented in your `tick` function wich is called every frame in the game like this:
`spriteVel += timeSinceLastCall*accValue'

Also in this function update the position of the sprite like this:
`spritePos = timeSinceLastCall*spriteVel`

That will produce a smooth and realistic (if using the second approach) sprite movement

To enable accelerometer add this code at your layer init method

```
isAccelerometerEnabled = YES;
[[UIAccelerometer sharedAccelerometer] setUpdateInterval:(TIMER_INTERVAL)];
```

where TIMER_INTERVAL is a required for you interval (1./30 for example)

implement this function in your layer too to save the accelerometer measures

```
- (void)accelerometer:(UIAccelerometer*)accelerometer didAccelerate:    (UIAcceleration*)acceleration{

}
```

It is also possible to update sprite acceleration/velocity/position in this function

**EDIT:**

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIAcceleration_Class/Reference/UIAcceleration.html

```
- (void)accelerometer:(UIAccelerometer*)accelerometer didAccelerate:    (UIAcceleration*)acceleration{

}
```

just take the acceleration vector from acceleration variable

for example x:

```
float accX = [acceleration x];
```